# Update models based on association record value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have thousands of price comparators where each of them have many products. The comparator has an attribute `:minimum_price` which is the minimum price of it's products. What would be the fastest way to update all comparators `:minimum_price`

**Comparator.rb**

```rb
has_many :products
```

**Product.rb**

```rb
belongs_to :comparator
```

Let's imagine the following:

```
comparator_1 have 3 products with a price of 3, 5, 7
comparator_2 have 2 products with a price of 2, 4
```

How could I update all comparators `:minimum_price` in one query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating all in one query will require the use of a [CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/) which are not supported by default by `ActiveRecord`. There are libraries that provide you with tools to use them in Rails (e.g. [this](https://github.com/vlado/activerecord-cte)) or you can also do it with a direct query like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
  update comparators set minimum_price = min_vals.min_price
  from (
    select comparators.id as comp_id, min(products.price) as min_price 
    from comparators inner join products on comparators.id = products.comparator_id
    group by comparators.id
  ) as min_vals
  where comparators.id = min_vals.comp_id
")
```

NOTE: This is a `postgresql` query, so the syntax may vary slightly if it's a different database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I don't know how you store your minimum values.

```
Comparator.update_all([
  'minimum_price = ?, updated_at = ?',
  Product.find(self.product_id).price, Time.now
])
```